# No description or tags returned using Microsoft Computer Vision API

Tags: android, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I want to make an android app using Microsoft's computer vision API, and what I wanted to do is to capture an image and return tags or caption which describes the image.My problem is that it does return wrong json data. Here is so far what I have done...

*process* method under **AnalyzeActivity.java**

```
 private String process() throws VisionServiceException, IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String[] features = {"ImageType", "Color", "Faces", "Adult", "Categories"};
    String[] details = {};


    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());

    AnalysisResult v = this.client.analyzeImage(inputStream, features, details);

    String result = gson.toJson(v);
    Log.d("result", result);

    return result;
}
```

onPostExecute method under AnalyzeActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);

    mEditText.setText("");
    if (e != null) {
        mEditText.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        this.e = null;
    } else {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        AnalysisResult result = gson.fromJson(data, AnalysisResult.class);
        mEditText.append("Definition: ");
        mEditText.append("Image format: " + result.metadata.format + "\n");
        mEditText.append("Image width: " + result.metadata.width + ", height:" + result.metadata.height + "\n");

        for (Category category: result.categories) {
            mEditText.append("Category: " + category.name + ", score: " + category.score + "\n");
        }


       for (Caption caption: result.description.captions) {
            mEditText.append("Caption: " + caption.text + ", confidence: " + caption.confidence + "\n");
        }
        mEditText.append("\n");

        for (String tag: result.description.tags) {
            mEditText.append("Tag: " + tag + "\n");
        }
        mEditText.append("\n");

    }

}
```

Here is the error message from logcat

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: myapp.capstone.com.lumineux, PID: 1693
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'java.util.List
>   com.microsoft.projectoxford.vision.contract.Description.captions' on a
>   null object reference
>   at
>   myapp.capstone.com.lumineux.AnalyzeActivity$doRequest.onPostExecute(AnalyzeActivity.java:152)
>                                                                                          at
>   myapp.capstone.com.lumineux.AnalyzeActivity$doRequest.onPostExecute(AnalyzeActivity.java:91)
>                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
>                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Your response will not contain captions unless you request it.  You have two options:

(1) Call the `/analyze?visualFeatures=Description` endpoint.  In your example you would achive this by changing the one line to the following:

```
String[] features = {"Description"};
```

(2) Call the `/describe` endpoint.  For the SDK in question you would invoke the [DescribeActivity](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Android/blob/master/Sample/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/projectoxford/visionsample/DescribeActivity.java) instead of the **AnalyzeActivity**.  In other words you'd call:

```
AnalysisResult v = this.client.describe(inputStream, 1);
```

The second method is simpler, and will also give you the opportunity to get more than one candidate sentence (by changing the second argument.)   The first is more convenient if you want some other feature *in addition to* the description, such as `Faces`.